# Why do we change an IP address's network mask when adding it to routher rules from /23 to /32?

Tags: router, firewall, subnet, network

I am getting ready for the security+ exam, and I don't understand something in a video of security+ performance based question, In that video we were adding rules to the firewall for a group of computers to communicate to a server. The computer's IP address was 110.4.80.10/231, its subnet was `255.255.255.254`, the server's IP address was `10.4.81.5/24`, and its subnet is obviously `255.255.255.255`. In that video he changed the subnet of the source IP address to `10.4.80.10/32`, and the same with the destination IP address `10.4.81.5/32`. The protocol was TCP and the port number was `443` for HTTPS.

I don't understand why he changed the subnet to `/32` for both of them.

[This si The Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4q8EAsGhP8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to which video are you referring, but let me go this one by one:

1. From the networking point of view, IPv4 addresses, be it both source or destination addresses, don't carry a concept of network mask. Network masks are used only by routers to decide where to route the packet. You can take a look at the IP header and notice, there's no network mask anywhere - it's only source and destination address: [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1%20*RFC%20791*). We can brag about classful and classless routing (but it's 2017 for Gods sake!), so lets leave it out from a discussion for clarity.
2. From the security point of view (and that *may* be it, I'm not sure from your vague description), yes - sometimes firewalls do base their rules on the concept of matching not only source or destination address (`10.4.80.10` and `10.4.81.5` in your example), but also a network mask. This is a strange and usually not intuitive way to match the *interface* the packet should be checked against - on some older and more clunky gear that is the way implementation of the [uRPF](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/security-center/unicast-reverse-path-forwarding.html) mechanism works. uRPF in essence tries to check if source (node) is not spoofing its IP address.
3. *Maybe*, and I'm guessing here, the video demonstrated that to match specific host, you need to specify `/32` for IPv4 addresses (or `/128` for IPv6 addresses) to signify it's a host, not a network. But again - I'm guessing here, you haven't provided URL of the video to which you're referring.

And no, `/24` is not "obviously" `255.255.255.255`, it's `255.255.255.0` - you can play with various subnet masks on great site at [subnetmask.info](http://subnetmask.info/) - one of many of it's kind.

Comment: Nor is "`10.4.80.10/23` and its subnet was `255.255.255.254`" accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your firewall rule needs to only let one (1) IPv4 address through (IPv4 address `10.4.80.10`), the network mask of `255.255.255.255` indicates to the firewall you are limiting access to just one IPv4 address.  The `/32` is a different but equivalent notation for the network mask of `255.255.255.255`.

If you left the network mask as `255.255.254.0`, which is equivalent to the `/23` notation, then your firewall rule would be saying to the firewall that you want to let a range of IPv4 addresses through (not just the single IPv4 address of `10.4.80.10`).  The `/23` notation references a range of 510 valid IPv4 addresses.